# SDcard support in Linux for ENE Flash UB6250 card reader (found on Acer Aspire One 522)

Tags: linux-kernel, sd-card, netbook

I have an Acer Aspire One 522 netbook for which I want to get the SDcard reader working, but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize the SDcard after it is inserted.

I use Slackware and always compile my own kernels, so I have already enabled the `Device Drivers->MMC/SD/SDIO card support` option and respective kernel modules, compiled and properly installed the kernel and its modules (kernel version is 3.5.3).

The card reader seems to get connected to the USB bus as soon as a SDcard is inserted, since `lsusb` only shows the reader after this event:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf2:6250 ENE Technology, Inc. SD card reader (UB6250)
```

I would normally expect to see a block device like `/dev/mmcblk0` and the card partitions (`/dev/mmcblk0p1`, `/dev/mmcblk0p2` and so on) after the card is inserted, but nothing shows up. Monitoring /var/log/messages while the card is inserted shows this:

```
Sep  8 14:43:41 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf2, idProduct=6250
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: Product: UB6250       
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: Manufacturer: ENE Flash  
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire kernel: usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 606569746801
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-2" 
Sep  8 14:43:44 aspire mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

showing the reader being connected to the USB bus but with no block device being detected. Does anyone have any hints about this? Did I miss something or support for this reader is not completely functional yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rebooting on the generic Slackware kernel I noticed the SDcard was detected as a SCSI device - dmesg output follows:

```
[  205.694553] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  205.812086] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf2, idProduct=6250
[  205.812100] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  205.812109] usb 2-2: Product: UB6250       
[  205.812116] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: ENE Flash  
[  205.812122] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 606569746801
[  205.841074] scsi3 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  205.842222] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums_eneub6250
[  205.848453] keucr: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  205.850027] usb --- usb_stor_init start
[  205.850103] usbcore: registered new interface driver eucr
[  205.850109] ENE USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  207.175693] scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
[  207.175714] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access                                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  207.177069] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3911680 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.86 GiB)
[  207.177250] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  207.177262] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[  207.177437] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[  207.177445] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  207.179216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[  207.179230] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  207.208861]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
[  207.209959] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[  207.209971] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  207.209980] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

The line `ENE USB Mass Storage support registered` hinted there was something missing related to USB support, so I found this option which was turned off: `Device Drivers->USB Support->USB ENE card reader support`. After recompiling the kernel including this module it was possible to access the SDcard as usual through the associated SCSI block device.